# "busting in their crib" what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

"Draftpicks busting in their cribs" that said one of the man from basketball video "Game of zones" and I'm not sure what does it mean...Does it mean screaming or dying? is that means that nobody take care of them? 
Thank you for any answer in advance!

Comment: Can you link to the episode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they are hanging out/having fun. Draftpicks - new players picked for the team. Busting - a verb describing hanging out, dancing, or drinking. Cribs - houses.

Comment: If it helped, could you accept my answer?

Comment: @MingChang - Please don't encourage our newer users to accept an answer, particularly within minutes of posting it. Our normal custom is to [wait at least half a day or so](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: This makes sense but it may be a fairly recent slang redefinition of "bust", which is why it's difficult to find in any online references.  Be aware that the verb "bust" has many slang meanings, in addition to its many more "formal" meanings.